# Hybris installation error

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

D:\HYBRIS Soft copies\hybris\bin\platform>setantenv.bat

Setting ant home to: D:\HYBRIS Soft copies\hybris\bin\platform\apache-ant-1.9.1
Apache Ant(TM) version 1.9.1 compiled on May 15 2013

```
D:\HYBRIS Soft copies\hybris\bin\platform>ant clean all


Buildfile: D:\HYBRIS Soft copies\hybris\bin\platform\build.xml

[echo] D:\HYBRIS Soft copies\hybris\bin\platform/tomcat/bin

[mkdir] Created dir: D:\HYBRIS Soft copies\hybris\log

[mkdir] Created dir: D:\HYBRIS Soft copies\hybris\data

[mkdir] Created dir: D:\HYBRIS Soft copies\hybris\temp\hybris

[input]

[input]  **** NO CONFIG FOLDER FOUND ****

[input]

[input]  No config folder was found at D:\HYBRIS Soft copies\hybris\config.

[input]  A "fresh" folder containing basic configuration files and the hybris

[input]  demo licence will be created for your convenience.

[input]  Please adjust and review the configuration files (and license) and

[input]  call 'ant' again. This directory will never be overridden or

[input]  touched again. Always use this configuration folder for configuration

[input]  of platform, do not change anything within the platform folder.

[input]

[input]  Please choose the configuration template.

[input]  Press [Enter] to use the default value ([develop], production)

[copy] Copying 26 files to D:\HYBRIS Soft copies\hybris\config

[copy] Copying 1 file to D:\HYBRIS Soft copies\hybris\config

[ysetplatformproperties] Web root <web> of the extension <testweb> has been explicitely disabled


[ysetplatformproperties] java.util.Objects.requireNonNull(Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;

[ysetplatformproperties] java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: java.util.Objects.requireNonNull(Ljava/lang/Object;)L
g/Object;

[ysetplatformproperties] at de.hybris.ant.taskdefs.internal.context.TomcatContext$SimpleElement.<ini
tContext.java:222)

[ysetplatformproperties] at de.hybris.ant.taskdefs.internal.context.TomcatContext$SimpleElement.<ini
tContext.java:220)

[ysetplatformproperties] at de.hybris.ant.taskdefs.internal.context.TomcatContext.<init>(TomcatConte
81)

[ysetplatformproperties] at de.hybris.ant.taskdefs.SetPlatformProperties.createTomcatContext(SetPlat
erties.java:623)

[ysetplatformproperties] at de.hybris.ant.taskdefs.SetPlatformProperties.setAllProperties(SetPlatfor
ies.java:494)

[ysetplatformproperties] at de.hybris.ant.taskdefs.SetPlatformProperties.execute(SetPlatformProperti
117)

[ysetplatformproperties] at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:292)

[ysetplatformproperties] at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)

[ysetplatformproperties] at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessor
a:43)

[ysetplatformproperties] at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:613)

[ysetplatformproperties] at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:1

[ysetplatformproperties] at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)

[ysetplatformproperties] at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:435)

[ysetplatformproperties] at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.ProjectHelper2.parse(ProjectHelper2.java:168

[ysetplatformproperties] at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.ImportTask.importResource(ImportTask.java:

[ysetplatformproperties] at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.ImportTask.execute(ImportTask.java:162)

[ysetplatformproperties] at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:292)

[ysetplatformproperties] at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)

[ysetplatformproperties] at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.jav

[ysetplatformproperties] at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessor
a:43)

[ysetplatformproperties] at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:613)

[ysetplatformproperties] at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:1

[ysetplatformproperties] at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)

[ysetplatformproperties] at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:435)

[ysetplatformproperties] at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.ProjectHelper2.parse(ProjectHelper2.java:179

[ysetplatformproperties] at org.apache.tools.ant.ProjectHelper.configureProject(ProjectHelper.java:9

[ysetplatformproperties] at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.runBuild(Main.java:826)

[ysetplatformproperties] at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.startAnt(Main.java:235)

[ysetplatformproperties] at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.run(Launcher.java:280)

[ysetplatformproperties] at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:109)

BUILD FAILED

D:\HYBRIS Soft copies\hybris\bin\platform\build.xml:20: The following error occurred while executing this l

D:\HYBRIS Soft copies\hybris\bin\platform\resources\ant\antmacros.xml:114: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: jav
bjects.requireNonNull (Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;

 at de.hybris.ant.taskdefs.internal.context.TomcatContext$SimpleElement.<init>(TomcatContext.java:22

at de.hybris.ant.taskdefs.internal.context.TomcatContext$SimpleElement.<init>(TomcatContext.java:22

at de.hybris.ant.taskdefs.internal.context.TomcatContext.<init>(TomcatContext.java:81)
at de.hybris.ant.taskdefs.SetPlatformProperties.createTomcatContext(SetPlatformProperties.java:623) 

at de.hybris.ant.taskdefs.SetPlatformProperties.setAllProperties(SetPlatformProperties.java:494)

at de.hybris.ant.taskdefs.SetPlatformProperties.execute(SetPlatformProperties.java:117)

at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:292)

at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)

at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)

at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:613)

at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106  

at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348) 

at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:435) 

at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.ProjectHelper2.parse(ProjectHelper2.java:168) 

at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.ImportTask.importResource(ImportTask.java:230) 

at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.ImportTask.execute(ImportTask.java:162) 

at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:292) 

at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) 

at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) 

at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) 

at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:613) 

at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106) 

at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348) 

at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:435) 

at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.ProjectHelper2.parse(ProjectHelper2.java:179) 

at org.apache.tools.ant.ProjectHelper.configureProject(ProjectHelper.java:93) 

at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.runBuild(Main.java:826) 

at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.startAnt(Main.java:235) 

at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.run(Launcher.java:280) 

at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:109) 

Total time: 27 seconds
```

Comment: You have received several down-votes because you have simply pasting a log error with no context, no information about what you are trying to achieve and no question posed.
You are lucky that contributors are smart enough to figure out what you are trying to do from the log and make suggestions.

Comment: Please update the directory path for bin and config.

Answer (score 18):

1. Please, move hybris into **shorter folder without spaces** (it's may can lead to really strange errors)
2. Check your JDK version (1.7)
3. When you just unpack your hybris archive you must have only two folders in $HYBRIS/hybris

   - bin
   - sampleconfiguration

Next you need to move to

$HYBRIS/hybris/bin/platform

and call:

> ./setantenv.bat

next

> ant clean

and choose your profile (develop)

after all you may use

> ant all

for build your hybris app.

Answer (score 4):

Please extract your folder again in a folder with shorter name. And, use 7-zip to extract the folder as there may be some issues related to your extraction.

Answer (score 4):

look at the path must not contain spaces

Answer (score 3):

This error comes because of spaces of your hybris installation path. Make sure there should not have any space in your full path of each segments.

Answer (score 2):

Its because space in the directory path.

Answer (score 2):

I will suggest you to use recipe installer and do't keep spaces in directory name. It's easy...

Go to platform directory and run below command
Step 1: . ./setantenv.sh (For Mac)
setantenv.bat (For Windows)

Step 2: Goto Hybris installer directory and run below command
Note: You will find installer directory inside hybris directory
./install.sh -r sap_som_b2b (for Mac)
install.bat -r sap_som_b2b (for Windows)

** Copied from:
https://www.queshub.com/how-to-install-sap-hybris-using-recipe-installer-

Answer (score 1):

first check jdk available or not,if not available download and install set the path(env varible)

then check java version
- download hybris software(more than 2gb)...then unzip software go to installer or bin based on the vesrion 
install.bat -r b2c_acc or setantenv.bat
after completion
ant clean all
install.bat -r b2c_acc initialize  or
after completion login Hybris admin console ex- http://localhost:9002/hac/hybris
there u find the tab initialize(only one time in project other wise every thing wiped out)

Answer (score 0):

The path is the problem.

1. Check if the folder exists in file explorer then,
2. Use forward slash common in entire path "C://dir1/dir2/"
3. Keep the folder near to root.
4. Don't have spaces in between the directory name.